# Virtual Memory Exhaustion - Is This To Blame?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm getting an unusual and constant build up of virtual memory as I navigate through my app, which is leading to boggy performance and eventually a memory pressure crash. App physical memory never goes past 10mb to 20mb, virtual memory however is peaking in the 200mb to 300mb range at the time of crash.

I'm using ARC.

Basically, I'm thinking the problem is the approach I've taken to my cellForRowAtIndexPath / itemForRowAtIndexPath methods, as the app is very intensely based on content provided through tableviews and collection views.

Basically, what I'm doing is dequeueing cells registered to custom XIB files, that do not have a class file (Which I think is the problem) and then referencing the objects of those dequeued cells through tags rather than them as a class and accessing their properties.

From my code, and from what I'm gathered, I'm assuming any time my collection views or tables reload, it's basically created additional cells where it doesn't need to as cells have already been created, so it's just overlaying the same content on the same cells? That or using UILabel *name = (UILabel *)etc.. is increasing the reference count in places it shouldn't be, which is causing memory usage to skyrocket as objects aren't being deallocated?

Here's a snippet of code from one of the most intensive portions of the app for creating items, is my logic / flow causing my virtual memory problems?

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:PRODUCTS_FEED_CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *product = [self.productsFeedItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIImageView *productThumbnailView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:PRODUCTS_FEED_COLLECTION_ITEM_TAG_THUMBNAIL];
    [productThumbnailView setImageWithURL:[APIController resourceUrlForUserId:[product objectForKey:@"userId"] resourceName:[product objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]]];

    UILabel *productPriceLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:PRODUCTS_FEED_COLLECTION_ITEM_TAG_PRICE];
    productPriceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", [product objectForKey:@"price"]];

    NSString *likeImage = ([[product objectForKey:@"liked"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) ? @"feedLikeSelected.png" : @"feedLikeUnselected.png";
    UIButton *productLikeButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:PRODUCTS_FEED_COLLECTION_ITEM_TAG_LIKE];
    [productLikeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:likeImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return cell;
}
```

Heap Allocations & Instruments Screenshot

[image]
[image]

Comment: please add editable code, not images

Answer (score 0):

The problem could come from the fact that the images you are trying to get from the server are huge. Check the sizes of the images you are setting with `setImageWithURL:`. Also, are you caching those images?

Comment: I'm using SDWebImage, so those images are indeed being cached. Most images are 640x640. Creating thumbnail image variations for each image depending on where it's being used / scaled would probably help. But I can't imaging that being the cause of VM soaring to 200mb / 300mb? Shouldn't those imageviews be released and freed from memory when navigating to and from views within the app anyways?

Comment: Have you tried to use memory profiling to see what are the objects that are most memory consuming? I think that 640x640 images being retained in the memory are the actual source of your problem.

Comment: Added two screenshots to the original post.

Comment: Just for the sake of testing, I shrank all of the images my app pulls from the server from 640x640 down to 64x64 using a batch process to see if that was the issue, and it was not apparently. The app still became sluggish after a short period of use and crashed.. Very confusing.

Comment: That is strange indeed... Well, you can try commenting out parts of code one by one and try to identify when your memory consumption starts soaring.